# Lifting the exponent $\,\nu_2(x^n\!-y^n) = \nu_2(x-y)+\nu_2(n),$ odd $x,y,\ 4\mid x-y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I am trying to understand the proof of theorem 3 (in p.4) in [this AoPS expostion on Lifting the Exponent](https://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvMi8xL2IwYTgxOTAyOTVlMmE0OTY4Zjk5YjVmZWY0MzQ5ZjUyMzIwMWVi&rn=TGlmdGluZyBUaGUgRXhwb25lbnQgLSBWZXJzaW9uIDYucGRm) (excerpted below).

However, I dont understand the last sentence "This means the power of $2$ in all of the factors in the above product (except $x-y$) is one and we are done."

We have $x+y\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$. Hence $x^{2^n}-y^{2^n}\equiv 2^n(x-y) \pmod{4}$, but why this will imply the result we want? Pleas helps, thank you so much.

edit: It is equivalent to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}v_2(x^{2^k}+y^{2^k})=n$.

---

[image]

Comment: I think it would be better if this problem were self-contained (that is, if it had enough information so that I wouldn't have to go to another website to understand it).

Comment: The article is _Amir Housein Parvardi_, Lifting The Exponent Lemma (LTE), 2011. It can now be found e.g. here: http://www.taharut.org/imo/I5775/LTE.pdf

Comment: You can find or request more details at ProofWiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lifting_The_Exponent_Lemma_for_p%3D2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that $x^{2^k}$ and $y^{2^k}$ are either both congruent to 1 or both congruent to -1 mod 4.  Thus when you add them, you get something congruent to 2 mod 4, and if something is congruent to 2 mod 4, it has exactly one power of 2 in its prime factorization.